# Do Multiple Linq To Entity Queries In Entity Framework Using One DBContext Connect Only Once To The Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to return two result sets from an SQL Server database using Entity Framework 6.  I would like to try this by running 2 Linq to Entity queries using a single DBContext.  My question is by using a single DBContext is whether my request is only being hit by a database connection once. I think it is but I am not sure.

```
class RequestRefLists
{
  public List<Employee> EmployeeList {get;set;}
  public List<Dept> DeptList {get;set;}
}

    public RequestRefLists GetRequestRefLists()
   {
    RequestRefLists ReqRefLists = new RequestRefLists();

    using(var context= new BusinessDBContext())
    { 
      var queryResult1 = from e in context.Employees
      select e;
      ReqRefLists.EmployeeList = (List<Employee>)queryResult1.ToList();

      var queryResult2 = from d in context.Departments
      select d;
      ReqRefLists.DeptList = (List<Dept>)queryResult2.ToList();
    }
    return ReqRefLists;
   }
```

Comment: A simple glance at the executed SQL statements could have answered your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).

There is a feature named [Future queries](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries)

```
class RequestRefLists
{
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList {get;set;}
    public List<Dept> DeptList {get;set;}
}

public RequestRefLists GetRequestRefLists()
{
    RequestRefLists ReqRefLists = new RequestRefLists();

    using(var context= new BusinessDBContext)
    { 
        var queryResult1 = from e in context.Employees
        select e;
        ReqRefLists.EmployeeList = queryResult1.Future();

        var queryResult2 = from d in context.Departments
        select d;
        ReqRefLists.DeptList = queryResult2.Future();        
    }
    return ReqRefLists;
}
```

Your queries will execute lazy on first enumeration of any collection.

> ExecuteFutureQueries builds a batch query from all the stored
>   IFutureQuery objects. Finally, all the IFutureQuery objects are
>   updated with the results from the query.

Comment: Question is do entity framework hit database only once when using same dbcontext object for multiple linq.

Comment: @SundarSingh and Future() does exactly this.

Comment: If I understand it correctly it appears you can stack your queries within a single dbcontext each with the word .Future at the assignment point. In my case that is where I want to load a particular list in a custom class.  After all queries have been defined I just enumerate one of them and all the assignments to my class instance are supposed to be performed in a single database connection. I'll test this. I am trying to load all the lookup lists from tables for a UI. I wonder if the extensions are officially part of Entity Framework. Thanks Vadim.

Comment: There is no built mechanism to combine multiple queries in one batch. It is the reason of existence of EF Extended Library. Why do not you want to include 1 nuget package?